# Count Distinct and Sum at different group levels in single Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, count, grouping, distinct

Below is my query. Is there anyway to use different levels of group levels. I need to get product_count column to count distinct of Product_id but not at `account_id and acct_type_id level`.

Currently the product_count column is coming as 1 for each row. I just need to get a distinct count of product ids, and need short and long sales aggregated at `account_id,product_id, acct_type_id` level.

So I want the output to be like:

```
order_date account_id short_sales long_sales **product_count** price product_id acct_type_id <br>
31-Oct-19 6698777      -2800         500           **0**            30       100005      3 <br>
31-Oct-19 6998874      -4000         325           **0**            30       100005      2 <br>
31-Oct-19 5555555      -5000        1000           **0**            30       100005      3 <br>
31-Oct-19 4444444      -1000        5000           **1**            30       100005      2


select POS.ORDER_DATE,
POS.ACCOUNT_ID,
SUM(POS.SHORT_SALES) as SHORT_SALES,
SUM(POS.LONG_SALES) as LONG_SALES,
COUNT(Distinct POS.PRODUCT_ID) AS PRODUCT_COUNT,
POS.PRICE,
POS.PRODUCT_ID,
POS.ACCT_TYPE_ID 
from PRODUCT 

(             
SELECT P.ORDER_DATE, P.ACCOUNT_ID, P.PRODUCT_ID, P.ACCT_TYPE_ID,P.PRICE,case when P.POSITION_SD < 0 THEN P.NET_POSITION_SD END AS SHORT_SALES, 
case when P.POSITION_SD > 0 THEN P.NET_POSITION_SD END AS LONG_SALES 
        FROM PRODUCT P 
        WHERE P.POSITION_DATE = '31-OCT-19'
) POS 
group by POS.ORDER_DATE, POS.ACCOUNT_ID, POS.PRODUCT_ID, POS.ACCT_TYPE_ID,POS.PRICE 
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grouping sets` to define which columns you compute subtotals for.

List the set of columns you want a subtotal for inside parentheses:

```
with products as (
  select mod ( level, 3 ) product_id,
         mod ( level, 6 ) account_id,
         mod ( level, 2 ) acct_type
  from dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
  select product_id, account_id, acct_type, count(*)
  from   products
  group  by grouping sets (
    product_id,
    ( product_id, account_id, acct_type )
  );

PRODUCT_ID     ACCOUNT_ID     ACCT_TYPE     COUNT(*)   
            0             0            0           1 
            0             3            1           2 
            0        <null>       <null>           3 
            1             1            1           2 
            1             4            0           2 
            1        <null>       <null>           4 
            2             2            0           2 
            2             5            1           1 
            2        <null>       <null>           3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding to my question. I am looking for total count of product_id count =  3 based on your example. As I see 3 unique product_ids: 0,1,2. So I just need the unique counts of 3, however i am getting counts for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this with just switching COUNT to use windowing.

For this example, I commented out some of your query to make it easier to reproduce, but the only part I changed was the COUNT line.

Edit: updated to return the count of distinct product IDs, in only one of the rows, with the rest of the `product_count` values set to 0.

```
-- example data
with product as (select sysdate as order_date, 6698777 as account_id, -1400 as short_sales, 300 as long_sales, 100005 as product_id, 30 as price, 3 as acct_type_id from dual
    union select sysdate, 6698777, -1400, 200, 100005, 30, 3 from dual
    union select sysdate, 5555555, -5000, 1000, 100005, 30, 3 from dual
    union select sysdate, 6998874, -4000, 325, 100005, 30, 2 from dual)
-- query            
select POS.ORDER_DATE,
POS.ACCOUNT_ID,
SUM(POS.SHORT_SALES) as SHORT_SALES,
SUM(POS.LONG_SALES) as LONG_SALES,
count(distinct product_id) over () * case when row_number() over (order by product_id desc) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as product_count, -- changed this line
POS.PRICE,
POS.PRODUCT_ID,
POS.ACCT_TYPE_ID 
from (             
SELECT P.ORDER_DATE, P.ACCOUNT_ID, P.PRODUCT_ID, P.ACCT_TYPE_ID,P.PRICE,
    --case when P.POSITION_SD < 0 THEN P.NET_POSITION_SD END AS 
    SHORT_SALES, 
    --case when P.POSITION_SD > 0 THEN P.NET_POSITION_SD END AS 
    LONG_SALES 
        FROM PRODUCT P 
    --    WHERE P.POSITION_DATE = '31-OCT-19'
) POS 
group by POS.ORDER_DATE, POS.ACCOUNT_ID, POS.PRODUCT_ID, POS.ACCT_TYPE_ID,POS.PRICE 
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my query. However I am looking for 1 total from all 3 rows -  as Product count as there is only one unique product id with 100005. When I tried this - I got 3 (which is total number of rows) - and I want to find unique product ids -  total 1 for Product_Count. For example:  PRODUCT_COUNT, PRODUCT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID 0,1000005, 5555555 <br> 0,1000005, 6698777 <br>  1, 1000005, 6998874

Comment: I think I read too quickly. So you want all of the `PRODUCT_COUNT` rows to be zero, except for one row which holds the distinct count of product IDs in the whole query result set? I edited my answer to show that option.